# Inject C# code before build

Tags: c#, build, compilation, inject

How to inject a new code in existing C# code (not MSIL) before compiling, but not change .cs file?

Comment: Using partial methods/class can't help ?

Comment: No, it doesn't help. I need to inject a lot of similar code in different properties of classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Text Template Transformation Toolkit (T4)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) to handle this type of scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Use T4 templates which write to [partial class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) files.  This is the pattern used by Visual Studio--auto-generated code goes in partial files, while your code goes in the main .cs file.

Answer (score 2):

You may take a look at [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp).

Comment: With PostSharp, I can inject code in runtime, but not before compiling.

Comment: I'm pretty sure PostSharp injects code after compilation, but before runtime.

Comment: See compile time weaving: http://www.sharpcrafters.com/aop.net/compiletime-weaving

Comment: You says: "I'm pretty sure PostSharp injects code AFTER compilation...", but I need to inject code BEFORE compilation.

Comment: I know, I'm correcting you, "With PostSharp, I can inject code in runtime"

Answer (score 1):

You can using [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) or [Weavlyn](https://github.com/CoderNate/Weavlyn) which working with  [MSIL injection "IL Weaving"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189359/what-is-il-weaving)