# How do i create my custom lock statement in c#?

Tags: c#

I want to create my custom statements for the c# compiler to generate a try finally block.
Just like the lock statement.

Forexample

```
private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim _lockObject

private void MyMethod()
{
   MyWriteLock(lockObject)
   {

   }
}

private void MyMethod2()
{
   MyReadLock(lockObject)
   {

   }
}
```

Compiler should generate following code for me

```
private void MyMethod()
{
   try
   {
     lockObject.EnterWriteLock();
     .. statetments for the method    
   }
   finally 
   {
     _lockObject.ExitWriteLock();
   }
}

private void MyMethod2()
{
   try
   {
     lockObject.EnterReadLock();
     .. statetments for the method    
   }
   finally 
   {
     _lockObject.ExitReadLock();
   }
}
```

Comment: what about code snippets? See [Creating and Using IntelliSense Code Snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392(v=VS.100).aspx)

Answer (score 6):

You can't create your own statements in C#. The closest you can come for try/finally is a `using` statement:

```
using (lockObject.AcquireReadToken())
{
}
```

where `AcquireReadToken()` would acquire a read lock, and return an `IDisposable` which releases the lock when it's disposed.

Answer (score 2):

You should give a try to **ILWeaving**. I haven't tried that, but a lot of 'magic' can be done using ILWeaving. I use **NotifyPropertyWeaver** which uses ILWeaving to inject code.

[NotifyPropertyWeaver](http://github.com/SimonCropp/NotifyPropertyWeaver)

Refer this question

[What is IL Weaving?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189359/what-is-il-weaving)

Comment: Another option would be to use PostSharp

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with ILWeaving using one of the following

- Postsharp http://www.sharpcrafters.com/
- Fody http://code.google.com/p/fody/
- Raw Cecil http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil

However I think in this case making use of a 'using' statement as suggested by @JonSkeet would be the much simpler solution.

That is, of course, unless you are interested in learning about IL Manipulation. In which case  go for it :)