# C# Lambda ignore case

Tags: c#, lambda

I want to ignore case using this LAMBDA query:

```
public IEnumerable<StationDto> StationSearch(string search)
        {
            var data = GenerateDtos();

            var list = data.Where(x => x.StationName.Contains(search));




            //var searchDto = new SearchDto {



            return null;
        }



        private static IEnumerable<StationDto> GenerateDtos()
        {
            return new List<StationDto>()
            {
                new StationDto()
                {
                    StationId = 1,
                    StationName = "DARTFORD"
                },
                new StationDto()
                {
                    StationId = 2,
                    StationName = "DARTMOUTH"
                },
                new StationDto()
                {
                    StationId = 3,
                    StationName = "TOWER HILL"
                },
                new StationDto()
                {
                    StationId = 4,
                    StationName = "DERBY"
                },
                new StationDto()
                {
                    StationId = 5,
                    StationName = "lIVERPOOL"
                },
                new StationDto()
                {
                    StationId = 6,
                    StationName = "LIVERPOOL LIME STREET"
                },
                new StationDto()
                {
                    StationId = 7,
                    StationName = "PADDINGTON"
                },
                new StationDto()
                {
                    StationId = 8,
                    StationName = "EUSTON"
                },
                new StationDto()
                {
                    StationId = 9,
                    StationName = "VICTORIA"
                },
            };
        }
    }
```

If I search for "DAR" it will bring back two but "dar" brings back 0 items. 
How would I modify this query?

Comment: It appears all the names are capitalized. Why should you need to use `dar` instead of `DAR`?

Comment: @RogueCSDev it's mostly for robustness. I know that I can use to upper or to lower to get around it but I was wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: What if one of the stations is named `"FOODAR"`?  Would you expect your `"DAR"` (or `"dar"`) search to find that one?

Comment: @kdbanman Well the string dar is contained within foodar so I would expect it.

Comment: Thanks.  Just making sure your requirements don't have surprises.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about `x.StationName.Contains(search)` you could do

```
var list = data
  .Where(x => x.StationName.IndexOf(search, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
```

You could also add a `String` extension method

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool Contains(this string thisObj, string value, StringComparer compareType) 
    {
        return thisObj.IndexOf(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
    }
}
```

and use it like this

```
 var list = data
   .Where(x => x.StationName.Contains(search, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: this brings me back everything.

Comment: @nickgowdy: then it means everything match with search criteria :)

Comment: While this is more performant than `ToLower()` or `ToUpper()` case conversions, I think it is less readable.

Comment: @kdbanman: I agree about readability but `toLower()` seems too verbose too. I added an alternative using an extension method.

Comment: Oooh.  Nifty.  I didn't know C# supported patching primitives.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi Thank's Claudio, this is what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this would work:

```
var list = data.Where(x => x.StationName.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()));
```

Or

```
var list = data.Where(x => x.StationName.Contains(search, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Not sure the syntax is correct on the second. I think it is.

Comment: Both of these (especially the first one) are *far* more readable than `IndexOf(...) >= 0`.  Good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like below:

```
var list = data.Where(x => x.StationName.ToUpper().Contains(search.ToUpper()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could utilize [Fody](https://github.com/Fody) which is a [IL Weaving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189359/what-is-il-weaving) tool created for .net and use the [Caseless](https://github.com/Fody/Caseless) addon.

When utilizing this library you can write code like this (as per the documentation):

```
public bool Foo()
{
    var x = "a";
    var y = "A";
    return x == y;
}
```

but would be compiled as:

```
public bool Foo()
{
    var x = "a";
    var y = "A";
    return string.Equals(x, y, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

So that you don't have to remember to either set ignorecase or `ToUpper`/`ToLower`.  I don't know about you, but I can't think of a time when I actually wanted case sensitive compares of strings... this could be applied to the entire project so you never have to remember to do it again! :)

In your specific example, the existing code you're using of:

```
var list = data.Where(x => x.StationName.Contains(search));
```

would bring back all instances of "DAR" indiscriminate of case.

Answer (score 0):

This worked the best for me. I was needing to do contains on a List.

Extension Method:

```
public static bool In(this List<string> thisObj, string value)
{
    foreach (var v in thisObj)
    {
        if (v.Equals(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return true;
    };
    return false;
}
```

Usage:

```
public bool IsFound(string value){
    return someStringList.In(value);
}
```

I went with "In" to distinguish from the Contains method.